# How to convert excel file to pdf format by python in linux envs

Tags: python, excel, linux, function, pdf

I am creating a function to convert excel files to pdf format by Python, but my program runs on Linux (centOS 7). Are there any packages that can do this?

Comment: The simplest way probably is the PDF conversion of LibreOffice. `localc --headless --convert-to pdf tables.xlsx` will produce `tables.pdf`.